# Login cookieauthentication Identity with existing database credentials

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I am making a login function with CookieAuthentication. I want to log in with my Username only. I want this method to recognize the username in the database and login with that username and start a cookieauthentication. When I run it with the code I have now it will not give me an error, it just stays at the login view. I am really sorry for my bad English, I hope someone recognizes what I want to succeed.

My view @model SpelerDTO

```
  <form asp-action="login" method="post">
                    <label asp-for="SpelerNaam"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="SpelerNaam" asp-for="@Model.SpelerNaam" 
                     placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" />
                    <button>Sign in</button>
                </form>
```

Homecontroller login function

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(SpelerDTO speler, string ReturnUrl)
    {

        if (speler.SpelerNaam == spelerContainer.getName(speler).ToString())
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, speler.SpelerNaam)
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Login");
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl == null ? "/Home/BeginPagina" : ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
```

My container class method I use to get username

```
 public SpelerDTO getName(SpelerDTO speler)
    {
        SpelerDTO s = _context.GetByName(speler);
        return s;
    }
```

My DAL function to get spelerNaam from SPELER table

```
 public SpelerDTO GetByName(SpelerDTO speler)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Speler WHERE spelerNaam = @spelernaam";
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
               new KeyValuePair<string,string>("@spelernaam", speler.SpelerNaam)
            };

            DataSet results = ExecuteSql(sql, parameters);
            SpelerDTO c = Parser.Parser.DataSetToSpeler(results, 0);
            return c;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the cookie authentication related codes and the details error message?  Without these we couldn't know why your codes doesn't work well.

Comment: I've found the answer already, thankyou for your reply!

Comment: If possible, please post your solution and mark it as answer, so that other folks who faces the same issue could find the solution more easily.